# keydown not working for validating email

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just want that user enter only valid email for this i use below function

```
 $(this).keydown(function(event)
                {
                    var _event = event || window.event;
                    var key = _event.keyCode || _event.which;
                    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
                    var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');
                    console.log("===============key================"+key);
                if (email.test(key)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                   }else{
                       return true;
                   }


            });
```

but its not working and user can enter invalid keys as well like # please help...

Comment: what is your `$(this)`????

Comment: Could you provide a JS Fiddle?Where is the test function as well?

Comment: u can say its an Id of that attribute on which i want to apply

Comment: Satej Test is use to match regular expression